# Netbeans desconfigurado

Tags: netbeans, configuração

Olá,
Estava fazendo um trabalho da faculdade no Netbeans. Queria fazer um diagrama de UML do projeto, então instalei um plugin com mostra o link que se segue.
[Vídeo tutorial que mostra a instalação do plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRZbbS-_IB0)

Não consegui obter os mesmos resultados que ele, então fui mexendo em algumas coisas aleatoriamente, agora não consigo mais editar meus códigos. A janela de edição simplesmente não abre.

O que pensei foi desinstalar completamente o programa e reintalar para voltar as configurações originais.

Uso o SO Ubunto 16.04LTS, usei os seguintes comandos:

sudo apt-get remove --purge netbeans
sudo apt-get install netbeans

Quando abri o novamente o programa apresentava o mesmo comportamento.
então novamente usei os comandos:

sudo apt-get remove --purge netbeans
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install netbeans

Continua a mesma coisa.

[image: Print da tela caso ajude]

Comment: isso está bem com cara de ser configuração de usuário.

Comment: faça o seguinte: vá na pasta do seu usuário com o seguinte comando: `cd $HOME` e pesquise a pasta ou arquivo de configuração do NetBeans: `ls -a`, feche o NetBeans, renomeie ou copie para outra pasta as configurações, e inicie Novamente e veja se resolve.

Comment: Era isso cara. MUITO OBRIGADO. Foi mal a demora pra responder, semana cheia. Fiz o que me disse, e apos o ls -a dei o comando sudo remove -R .netbeans.

Comment: Não to conseguindo te marcar como resposta que resolveu o problema. Deve ser porque você comentou em vez de responder ? Se quiser,responda o tópico para marcar sua ajuda como solução. Novamente obrigado.

Comment: está lá, respondido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é configuração de usuário do Netbeans.

Faça o seguinte: vá na pasta do seu usuário com o seguinte comando:
cd $HOME

E pesquise a pasta ou arquivo de configuração do NetBeans:
ls -a

Feche o NetBeans, renomeie ou copie para outra pasta as configurações, e inicie Novamente e veja se resolve.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans para windows>>

Instalar plugin indo na aba "ferramentas>>plugins"
pesquisar por "easyUML" e instalar o mesmo..

depois de instalado criar um NOVO PROJETO >> UML>> UML Diagrams Project"

depois no clicar com o botão direito no mouse NO PROJETO QUE VOCÊ DESEJA CRIAR O UML e clicar em "easyUML Create Class Diagram" e selecionar o o projeto diagram.. isso vai criar um arquivo extensão .cdg no projeto diagram com o uml do seu projeto.